# if two features correlate exactly to the target variable, how does Decision Tree choose between them as the root node to split?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a dataset, that consists of three columns, A,B and X.

A and B are the feature columns and X is the target column. They are all numerical values. I am trying to predict which feature contributed to X.

The dataset is as follows

```
A B X
1 1 0
2 2 1
2 2 1
2 2 1
1 1 0
```

Features A and B are in direct correlation with our target X. On what basis does the [Decision Tree Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) manage to choose the root node?

I have a case, where it always chooses `A` as the root node, instead of `B` when `B` should be the root node. I am trying to understand how does it do that so I can find a solution for the problem.

### Update

A suggestion was made to use sample weight, and to add simulated data

```
  in A B X
   0 1 1 0
   1 2 2 1
   2 2 2 1
   3 2 2 1
   4 1 2 0 <- How to increase weights of these instances
   5 1 2 0 <- How to increase weights of these instances
   6 1 2 0 <- How to increase weights of these instances
   7 2 1 1
```

I am not sure how to target it using

```
dt.fit(X, y,sample_weight= )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page you linked to says this:

> The features are always randomly permuted at each split. Therefore, the best found split may vary, even with the same training data and `max_features=n_features`, if the improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits enumerated during the search of the best split. To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting, `random_state` has to be fixed.

So, it looks like it will be completely random if multiple features are precisely equally informative (which is the case in your question).

---

If you really want to force the classifier to prioritize splits based on column `B` over column `A` in such a case, I do have a... rather ''hacky'' idea you could try.

The `fit()` function ([documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit)) has an optional `sample_weight` parameter, for which the documentation says this:

> **sample_weight** : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or None
>
> Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted. Splits that would create child nodes with net zero or negative weight are ignored while searching for a split in each node. Splits are also ignored if they would result in any single class carrying a negative weight in either child node.

You could try assigning a weight of `1.0` to every instance actually in your data, and then add an additional "artificial" instance to the dataset in order to make splitting on one of the features less pure than the other. For example, you could copy one of your actual instances (say, the last one), but modify the `A` feature such that splitting based on `A` becomes less pure.

For example, for the dataset you have given in the question, you could add an artificial instance with `A = 2`, `B = 1`, `X = 0`. Then, to minimize the impact of such an artificial instance on the rest of your training, I'd recommend giving it a very low weight (like `0.01`).

I suspect this may work, but like I said, it's very "hacky", and might negatively affect the quality of your classifier a bit since you're adding data that isn't real.

Comment: Interesting. This would suggest that OP's problem shouldn't be occuring, right? Therefore if A is always being chosen over B, then we can say A is definitely more informative than B.

Comment: @Victor see the part on `sample_weight` I copied from documentation. If you choose to specify weights for samples, it should be array-like (e.g. list or numpy vector) of length equal to the number of instances. I'd recommend choosing a weight of `1.0` for all real data, and a lower weight (like `0.01`) for fake data. Only a single fake instance should be sufficient. So, if your first `n-1` instances are real, and the `n`th instance is fake, I'd create a vector of length `n` filled with `1.0`s, and then simply set the very last entry to `0.01` for example.